# Алгоритм очереди с приоритетом

Tags: python, алгоритм

Существует такая задача создания очереди с объектами, которые имеют коэффициенты приоритета.
То есть выборка из этой очереди должна происходить не только того объекта, который первый в очереди но и еще который наиболее достоин.

Первое решение примитивное, которое было реализовано: это создание нескольких очередей (массивов), и первым делом доставание объектов из более приоритетных массивов. Но здесь встала проблема, что сколько бы не стояли в очереди неприоритетные объекты (с низким коэффициентом) если будет много приоритетных то до них очередь никогда не дойдёт или будет доходить очень долго.
Тогда было придумано доставать поочередно сначала самых приоритетных, в след итерации наоборот от меньшего коэффициента к большему (и внутри массивов в порядке очереди).

Но первый способ получается слишком сложным и непонятным. Тогда решил попробовать сделать рандомную выборку из очереди. То есть уже не важно место в очереди, важен лишь коэффициент.
Собирается 1 массив куда дублируются элементы согласно их коэффициенту. Получается, что если у объекта коэффициент 5, то он находится 5 раз в этом массиве. И потом выбирается рандомный индекс из этого массива. И согласно теории вероятности все должны быть довольны в меру своего коэффициента. Но не могу точно понять не будет ли в этом случае кто-то очень долго ждать и стоит ли повышать коэффициент в зависимости от времени, которое находится в очереди. И так как не силён в алгоритмах, не уверен, что это решение точно будет работать.

Буду признателен, если кто-то знает подходящий алгоритм для моей задачи, или же подсказать в правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь.

Comment: Ну есть же такая структура данных - очередь по приоритетам. В Python, например, `import heapq`

Comment: Возможно в вашем случае нужно ввести понятие *динамического приоритета* (по которму и д.б. упорядочена очередь). Превоначальный динамический приоритет делаете равным вашему коэффициенту. Время от времени очередь просматривается, текущиий приоритет повышается в соответствии со временем пребывания в ней и она переупорядочивается. Для организации такой очереди, наверное, подойдет какое-то сбалансированное дерево (м.б. rb-tree или avl-tree)

Comment: Большое спасибо, рассмотрю эти варианты

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы малоприоритетные задачи в конце концов обрабатывались, им нужно время от времени повышать приоритет.

В схеме с несколькими очередями можно сделать так. По таймеру выбираете случайным образом очередь с низким приоритетом и перещаете объект из головы этой очереди в хвост очереди со следующим приоритетом. Если у вас `N` приоритетов, а позиция объекта в очереди своего приоритета `n`, то в среднем за `N*n` тактов таймера объект повысит свой приоритет. Это означает, что в конечном итоге каждый объект доберётся до максимального приоритета.

В этом сценарии главный параметр - это длительность такта. Если такт короткий, то малоприоритетные объекты будут быстро "всплывать" и забивать очередь высокоприоритетных. Если такт длинный, то время ожидания малоприоритетных будет слишком велико, и они могут отваливаться по таймауту (если такой есть). Нужно подбирать длительность такта экспериментально.

И общее замечание. Если у вас высокприоритетные объекты поступают слишком быстро, стоить перепроектировать систему и либо добавить вычислительных мощностей, чтобы быстрее обрабатывать их поток, либо как-то ограничить вход. А ещё можно поступить как в блокчейне Эфириума - если клиенты хотят, чтобы их транзакции обработали, пусть платят :)

UPDATE

Как подсказал @avp, приоритет можно повышать не только по таймеру.

Например, каждый раз, когда вы извлекаете объект из очереди, вы повышаете приоритет одному из малоприоритетных объектов.

UPDATE 2

У вашего метода со случайным взвешенным выбором есть несколько недостатоков:

- нарушается очерёдность объектов. Как правило, в системах потоковой обработки с приоритетами желательно, чтобы объекты одного приоритета обрабатывались в порядке добавления в очередь. Вместо очереди получается пул.
- нет гарантии, что объект будет обработан. Если сумма весов (вы называете их коэффициентами) объектов равна `W`, то время, за которое объект минимального приорета, будет обработан с вероятностью `1/2` можно оценить как `W*ln(2)`. Если очеред будет разрастаться, то будет расти суммарный вес `W`, и время ожидания тоже будет расти. Так как это вероятность, то вероятность того, что объект вообще не будет обработан за время работы программы, ненулевая.

Я бы делал повышение приоритета по таймеру.

Comment: imho вместо таймера на практике можно использовать последовательный номер обращения к очереди

Comment: Да, спасибо, надо попробовать реализовать что то подобное и экспериментально подобрать такт повышения приоретета. Спасибо, что указали на недостатки случайного выбора.